# Karatsuba Algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I implemented a Karatsuba algorithm in Python but it doesn't give me the exact answer.

```
def karatsuba(x, y):
    if x < 10 or y < 10:
        return x*y

    #making the two numbers strings here
    str_x = str(x)
    str_y = str(y)

    #finding the mid point for each number here
    n = max(len(str(x)), len(str(y)))
    n_2 = int(n / 2)

    #higher bits of each number
    x_h = int(str_x[:n_2])
    y_h = int(str_y[:n_2])

    #lower bits for each number here
    x_l = int(str_x[n_2:])
    y_l = int(str_y[n_2:])

    a = karatsuba(x_h, y_h)
    d = karatsuba(x_l, y_l)
    e = karatsuba(x_h + x_l, y_h + y_l) - a - d

    return a*10**len(str_x) + e*10**(len(str_x) // 2) + d


result = karatsuba(1234, 8765)
print(result)
```

I think its because I am taking integer values and ignore decimals of floating point values.

When I run the above program my answer is 10,402,010 whereas the actual answer is 10,816,010

How can I improve this?

Comment: Off topic: not [a specific working piece of code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). `karatsuba()` lacks a [doc string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

Comment: @greybeard - Can you please explain the whole doc string in more detail? I looked through the doc but I don't understand why my code requires that? Is it some sort of python convention?

Comment: `code` doesn't require anything - responsible coding does. You may *think* the code will be read by (machines and) yourself, only - even *if* that turns out to be true, a later you may be glad to see documented code. Then, code has an annoying tendency to be "quoted" (cut&pasted) out of context: minimise the need for clarifications, keep them close to the needy code, stick to conventions (if for tool support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Errors in the code**:

1. When you split `str_x[:n_2]` and `str_y[:n_2]` you're taking the same number of digits *from the most significant part* of each number. You need to instead take the same number of digits *from the least significant part* of each number.

For example, the cross multiplication step of `karatsuba(12 + 34, 87 + 65)` goes wrong:

You get `x` = 46 and `y` = 152 so `n_2` = 1 and `str_x[:n_2]` = '4' and `str_y[:n_2]` = '1'. These are not offset by the same amount!

Instead you could set

```
#higher bits of each number
x_h = int(str_x[:-n_2])
y_h = int(str_y[:-n_2])

#lower bits for each number here
x_l = int(str_x[-n_2:])
y_l = int(str_y[-n_2:])
```

Negative indices count from the end, and this is just what you want so that you pull out the same number of powers of ten from each. Then `str_x[:-n_2]` = `str_x[:-1]` = all but the last `n_2` = 1 digit of `x` which is 4, and `str_y[:-n_2]` = `str_x[:-1]` = all but the last `n_2` = 1 digit of `x` which is 15. This works the way it should

2. With or without the above fix, your code will crash when both numbers > 10 and one of them is twice (or more) as many digits as the other. Then one of the slices will be the empty string, and `int('')` throws an error as opposed to (as you would want) returning `0`.

A quick fix to this would be to make the higher part and lower part each a function, and check for the empty string. Alternatively, you could have a special case in `karatsuba` when `n_2 >= min(...)`

3. Finally, there's a bug in the return computation. Instead of `len(str_x)` you want `2 * n_2` and instead of `len(str_x) // 2` you want `n_2`.

**Some quick comments on issues other than the errors**

Using `str(x)` is not very efficient, and does a lot of extra work in what is supposed to be an implementation of an efficient way to multiply. For getting the basic ideas of the algorithm down, though, it's fine for a start and I won't complain too much.

But you should at least be aware that a better way would be to split the number into two pieces in base 2 and use bit string operations. This would be a good follow-up exercise. Specifically `x >> n` is the same as `x // 2**n` and `x << n` is the same as `x * 2**n` and these are much more efficient than base 10 operations.

Comment: Why do I need to change the len(str_x) to 2*n_2 and len(str_x) // 2 to n_2 ? Wouldn't those two things be equal?

Comment: @ZaidHumayun No. For example, if `len(str_x)` is odd (then it wouldn't equal `2 * n_2`). Or if `len(str_y)//2` is less than `len(str_x)//2` in which case `n_2` would be the former.